# How to get message id of a message through telegram python api

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

Ok, I know this is a newbie question but I've been stuck for a while now.

I just started using pythonTelegarmapi but I have no idea how to get `message_id` of a message. How do i do it?

```
import os
import telebot

API_KEY =  "API_KEY"

# Getting the bot instance
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY)

# Forward mesasage
# From https://core.telegram.org5/bots/api#forwardmessage
@bot.message_handler(commands=['forward'])
def forward(message):
    bot.forward_message('@send_to','@from', 1, False)
                                           ^^^
#                                          Here is supposed to be the message_id but I don't know how to get that. 

"""
```

So, how to I retrieve the ID of a particular message in a chat/channel using Python Telegram Bot Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need:

```py
bot.forward_message(mydebugid, message.chat.id, message.message_id, False)
```

Where `mydebugid` is the ID you're forwarding to.

---

```py
import os
import telebot

API_KEY = "--"

# Getting the bot instance
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY)

mydebugid = 123456

bot.send_message(mydebugid, "Wake")

# Forward mesasage
@bot.message_handler(commands=['forward'])
def forward(message):
    bot.forward_message(mydebugid, message.chat.id, message.message_id, False)


bot.polling()
```

[image]

Comment: Must mydebugid be a number? Can it also be a string e.g '@from'

Comment: As per https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage it can not

Answer (score 0):

It's in the `message` parameter that your function is receiving. `message.message_id` should do the trick, see also https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#types. Note that instead of `'@from'` you should probably rather pass `message.chat.id` because IISC your code snippet doesn't guarantee that `message` will be a message sent in the chat identified by the username `'@from'`.